# Are we too [exposed]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exposed) tag usually doesn't bring much to the questions. It has only 28 questions which are about a range of topics, 2 followers and no guidance. It might be beneficial to create a tag for the Exposed SQL Framework though.

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  No. The questions with this tag may refer to: [the Exposed SQL Framework](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520895/kotlin-exposed-does-not-commit-transaction), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526340/noclassdeffounderror-when-using-exposed), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512447/maven-import-dependency-jetbrains-exposed)), exposing functions in C ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174078/expose-only-required-functions-in-c)), [xposed-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519764/xposed-invoke-method-via-broadcast-receiver)), OAuth ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415983/oauth-2-0-implicit-grant-flow-clientid-and-accesstoken-exposure-security)), Android image processing ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396009/how-to-expose-light-image-in-android)), other ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858488/gwt-native-function-reference-per-string), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114273/android-camera2-api-muti-frames-with-different-exposed-in-burstcapture), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990339/msscriptcontrol-specified-cast-is-not-valid-when-exposing-an-object-to-vbscrip), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781171/net-private-application))
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Yes.
- > Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  It depends but usually not. The exception is the Exposed SQL Framework which probably should get it's own tag.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  Not at all. See "Does it describe the contents of the questions..."

Comment: The few posts tagged [tag:exposed] and `[drupal*]` were an easy re-tag to (the existing tag) [tag:drupal-exposed-filter], so I went ahead and did that.

Comment: Bad tags [exposed]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exposed) is just too vague. What we need to do is replace this with more specific tags

I created [kotlin-exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-exposed) and retagged all the recent [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) questions (6 of them)

The remaining 20 just need retags... There's clearly some people who are just using it literally ( [How should I make a constant visible between multiple projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622089/how-should-i-make-a-constant-visible-between-multiple-projects) has nothing to do with SQL)